# Windows 11 Reset PC options

Tags: windows, windows-11, reset, factory-defaults

Suppose I want to reset my PC (laptop) to factory defaults. It was shipped with Windows 11 and some preinstalled apps. Windows 11 provides several options to reset the PC. From the [Microsoft website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/recovery-options-in-windows-31ce2444-7de3-818c-d626-e3b5a3024da5#WindowsVersion=Windows_11):

[image: Options]

However, it seems like there is no option to do what I want: To "remove everything" but "restore any apps the PC manufacturer installed". At least that's my understanding of factory defaults. Is there a specific reason why this option doesn't exist? Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the Recovery USB from the Computer Manufacturer.

Use this to reinstall the Computer.

The result will be identical with the day you got the computer including the Manufacturer Apps.

I use Lenovo laptops and that is how the Manufacturer Recovery USB works.

Reset by Microsoft may not include the Manufacturer Apps, so the Manufacturer USB is best for you

Answer (score 0):

Although [John's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1751605/1745562) is generally true, I want to add an alternative answer for Acer laptops and how I was finally able to achieve this. Unfortunately Acer doesn't ship a recovery USB with the device and there's no way to download a free image online. Instead you can buy a rather expensive recovery USB from their shop by providing your product SNID.

However, Acer recommends an alternative way to create a recovery drive for their devices from the recovery partition, as described on their website [here](https://community.acer.com/en/kb/articles/129-acer-recovery-media) for example. Summarized: Use the "Create a recovery drive" Windows tool with "Back up system files to the recovery drive." enabled.

However, since Acer devices already have such a recovery partition, the recovery drive (USB) isn't actually necessary to carry out a factory reset. According to their website [here](https://community.acer.com/en/kb/articles/14751-how-to-factory-reset-windows), all the options above in my question should work fine (can't confirm). I have used the "Alt"+"F10" Troubleshoot menu, which worked fine. Everything was removed but all preinstalled apps are present (as described in the Troubleshoot menu).